# Access query compare datetime to year only date?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, vba, ms-access, datetime

I have the following SQL query in my Access database, connected to SQL Server 2008:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as mCount 
FROM [Projects]
WHERE [DateProjectSubmitted]>'2014';
```

This works great and accomplishes exactly what I need.

However, I cannot seem to adapt the query for work within Access within a function I have (all error handling removed):

```
Public Function getNumberOfYearToDateProjects() As Integer
    Dim rsMyRecordSet As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sSql As String


    Set rsMyRecordSet = New ADODB.Recordset
    sSql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as mCount FROM [Projects] WHERE [DateProjectSubmitted]>#" & Format(Date, "YYYY") & "#"

    rsMyRecordSet.Open sSql, CurrentProject.Connection
    getNumberOfYearToDateProjects = rsMyRecordSet.Fields("mCount")

End Function
```

I know Access wants `#` symbols in the date expression but I cannot seem to make it recognize `2014` as a date for purposes of comparison.

If I copy the SQL directly, I run into problems with data mismatches.

I could do the following, but this just seems ugly

```
sSql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as mCount FROM [Projects] WHERE [DateProjectSubmitted]>#" & DateSerial(Year(Date), 1, 1) & "#"
```

Can I modify the SQL query or do I need to use something like `DateSerial` to create a fake 2014-01-01 date for the comparison?

Comment: What this question has to do with Sql Sever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that DateProjectSubmitted is a date field, and yourYear is a number

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as mCount FROM [Projects] WHERE YEAR([DateProjectSubmitted]) > " & yourYear
```